# PDF/X in pdflatex with memoir, new xcomply package

Tags: pdftex, memoir, pdfx

Only a question in the sense of feedback requested. Move if necessary...

For some time, I have been working on a better alternative to packages such as pdfx and xmpincl. I think I've got it! Results have been checked against professional software, and it seems to work just fine. No known bugs (hah!) but that's why I posted here.

BIG EDIT: My reason for doing xcomply was that pdfx was not satisfactory. But I was using an old version of pdfx, from my Linux distro. The new version, in CTAN and Miktex, is much, much better and solves almost all of the problems I saw before.

Yet in respose to a comment below, I looked at LuaTex. It turns out that package pdfx can be made to work with Luatex. Simply RequirePackage(ifluatex} and fork some of the pdfx code. If Luatex, also RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}. Then use pdf@mdfivesum with Luatex, instead of pdfmdfivesum. Also do not use the inputencoding commands with Luatex. This works with my own test examples, but I have not tested it exhaustively.

Will contact the pdfx maintainers when I am more certain. Also, I will show how to add the SWOP output intent popular in USA. Then, no need for xcomply.

Comment: This is good news, the existing packages never worked for me either. You do not need to be a developer to use Github, you can setup free repositories as long as they are public (but so is your website).

Comment: @ienissei: As a user, I tend to avoid GitHub. Some things are posted and never debugged, others are hard to download because partial code is strewn to several files. Anyway, since I have my own site, xcomply will sit there temporarily (unless some higher-up wants to take it over).

Comment: @RobtA Can it be used with LuaLaTeX ?

Comment: @ibn Saeed: I do not know if it can be used with LuaLaTeX, since I only use pdflatex and I am not an expert with LuaLaTeX. It is most essential that the engine be pdf(la)tex, not dvips. So XeTex definitely will not work. If you use LuaLaTeX with pdf(la)tex engine, then xcomply might work for you. The package does not change your document; it only changes the metadata. Can your document pass the ifpdf test? If it can, then xcomply might work. In every case, the metadata must be in Latin-1 character set. The package provides for writing Latin-1 metadata even if the document is utf or other.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question!